# default grails 4 app has unique-names twice in application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, grails, grails-4

Why does a default Grails 4 application including Grails 4.0.12 have two entries in the default generated application.xml reference the unique-names attributes.  We got this section near the top of the application.xml:

```
spring:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
```

and a second one that seem deprecated:

```
management:
    endpoints:
        jmx:
            unique-names: true
```

Should this second one be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second should be deleted. The Grails default configuration file (application.yml) is outdated and we are planning to clean it in the upcoming releases.

Meanwhile, I think this should be an issue at Grails Core. Also, would you be interested to send a pull-request at [github.com/grails-profiles/base](https://github.com/grails-profiles/base/blob/4.0.x/skeleton/grails-app/conf/application.yml) to remove the second value.

Comment: Thinking it is the Web version: 
 https://github.com/grails-profiles/web/blob/4.0.x/skeleton/grails-app/conf/application.yml

Comment: Created the pull request.  https://github.com/grails-profiles/web/pull/26